# Update varchar column records with random values from a joined table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following table:

```
subscriber(id_sub, name_sub)
              1    'Helen S.'
              2    'Marie S.'
```

The **name_sub** column records have to be updated, in order, with values taken randomly from the table:

```
targeted_subscriber(id, target_name)
                     1   'Damien B'
```

My intention was to use a JOIN clause in the UPDATE statement. Also, get random **id** values.

Is there an elegant, straightforward solution for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Cursor` to update random data in each row .Not sure whether this is the better way of doing

```
DECLARE @id_sub   INT,
        @name_sub VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT id_sub,
         name_sub
  FROM   subscriber

OPEN vendor_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id_sub, @name_sub

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      UPDATE subscriber
      SET    name_sub = (SELECT TOP 1 target_name
                         FROM   targeted_subscriber
                         ORDER  BY Newid())
      WHERE  id_sub = @id_sub

      FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id_sub, @name_sub
  END

CLOSE cur;

DEALLOCATE cur
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your "values taken randomly", I take it you mean dynamically?

If so, then a join clause is what I would use as well, akin to the following:

```
update subscriber
set name_sub = t.target_name
from subscriber s
join targeted_subscriber ts
on s.id_sub = ts.id
```

Comment: No, this certainly wouldn't fetch random values.

Comment: Then I definitely don't understand what you're saying in regards to random values. Random how? How many random values? Within a range?

Comment: Let's say the targeted_subscriber tables contains values like: 'Jay', ' Alejandro', 'Natalie' and so on. The update operation would change the 'Helen S.', 'Marie S' values with 'Natalie' and 'Alejandro', respectively

Comment: 'Random Values', or 'Random Records'?  If it is random records then you just need a random() function to select an Id.  If you want random values, the same applies, but use a different Id for each field.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I will leave it to you to adapt this to an update

```
select getRand.sID, getRand.value 
  from (  select docSVsys.sID, docEnum1.value, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by docSVsys.sID order by docEnum1.eRand) as rownum
            from ( select newid() sysRand, docSVsys.sID
                     from docSVsys
                    where docSVsys.sID < 100 ) docSVsys 
            join ( select newid() eRand, value 
                     from docEnum1 
                    where value is not null  
                      and value <> 'null'    ) docEnum1   
              on docSVsys.sysRand <= docEnum1.eRand  ) getRand 
  where getRand.rownum = 1
```